# python request module not downloading excel file

Tags: python, excel, python-requests

When I go to this link:
https://www.eia.gov/electricity/data/eia860m/archive/xls/september_generator2019.xlsx

The file downloads.

When I use requests, I don't get the actual file

```
import requests
     
url = 'https://www.eia.gov/electricity/data/eia860m/archive/xls/september_generator2019.xlsx'
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()
with open(path, 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(response.content)
```

this creates a file that excel cant open because the response.content isn't actually an excel file for some reason. In response.history I see that I'm redirected to https://www.eia.gov/cneaf/electricity/ for some reason.

pandas also raises an error

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(url, sheet='Operating')
```

but i'd rather not use pandas anyway..

Can someone explain what's going on and how i can fix it, preferably using the requests module and not much else

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me.  If you look at that file in a text editor, what do you see?  Are you, perhaps, going through a proxy that requires a redirect?

Comment: Not sure what 'going through a proxy that requires a redirect' means. When i look at what i'm actually getting it looks like this page: https://www.eia.gov/electricity/ . So i'm getting redirected somehow?

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall?  I literally cut-and-pasted your code and it worked first time.

Comment: No i'm not. And i've tried on multiple machines, using my wifi and a hotspot. Have you made sure you can actually open the downloaded file? It is the actual US EIA generator excel file?

Comment: Yes.  It came up in Excel just fine.

Comment: Is this working / not working for others?